# Are iOS applications required to have retina images?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

All my research indicates that the answer is "yes" but I'd like some external confirmation from a source I trust (either Apple.com or this site) as I have a bunch of non-retina images and would really prefer not to create retina graphics.

Answer (score 1):

No. You could submit an app with purely hand drawn images or 8 bit old school [graphics](http://make8bitart.com/) and [soundtrack](http://kindofbloop.com/)

The only *required* retina assets are the store icons and app icons as specified in the iOS HIG:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Comment: What about cartoon-ish graphics that were created in software? Do those get a pass, too? Also, not trying to be argumentative, but do you have any sources I can check to verify your answer? I know Apple requires HIG compliance, and the HIG  say I "should" have retina-ready images but don't expliticitly say I "must" do so.

Comment: @moonman239 Apple is precise about language. Should is permissive, must is binding. The quality of the art isn't in the tools, it's in the skill the chosen tools are used. I would decide how you want your app to look and submit it with the best execution of the tools you chose to create graphics assets.